# recyclerview sqlite database, data deleted on recyclerview but not deleting in database

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, delete-row

I want to delete both recyclerview and sqlite database, but the only recyclerview gets deleted.
When submitting a new record, the deleted records are visible.
Data is not deleted in the SQLite database.
How to delete data in SQLite database using recyclerview in android.

Here is my code.
AdapterClass

```
package com.example.recyclerviewsqlite;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHoder> {
    private ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
    private Context context;
    DBmain dBmain;
    
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList, Context context) {
        this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHoder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singledata, parent, false);
        return new ViewHoder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHoder holder, int position) {
        Model model = modelArrayList.get(position);
        holder.txtname.setText(model.getSname());
        holder.txtsub.setText(model.getSsubject());

//delete data
        holder.txtimag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            int newPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dBmain = new DBmain(context);
                dBmain.delete(newPosition);
                modelArrayList.remove(newPosition);
                notifyItemRemoved(newPosition);
                                notifyItemRangeChanged(newPosition, modelArrayList.size());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHoder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtname, txtsub;
        private ImageView icon, txtimag;

        public ViewHoder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
            txtsub = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsub);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            txtimag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtimg);

        }

    }
}
```

Database Class

```
package com.example.recyclerviewsqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME="student";
    public static final String TABLENAME="college";
    public static final int VER=1;
    public SqliteHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VER);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query="create table "+TABLENAME+"(id integer primary key, name text, subject text)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query="drop table if exists "+TABLENAME+"";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }



    public void delete(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //deleting row
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLENAME, "id=" + id, null);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this check this soluion

```
public void remove(String Id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(PE.TABLE_NAME, PE.COLUMN_PLACE_ID + "=\"" + Id+"\"", null) ;
}
```

and call this method when u want to delete

```
private void delete(int position){
      Dbhelper dbHelper = new Dbhelper(MainActivity.this);
      dbHelper.removePlace(arraylist.get(position).getPlaceId());
      arraylist.remove(position);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```